# General analytical solution for first order time varying system of ODEs

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I asked a question related to this previously, but not as explicitly as I should have, I'm restating it more concisely here.

Assume we are given some matrix $\mathbf{A}(t)$, which is time dependent. This matrix is square and not invertible.

A system:
$$
\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{x}(t)}{\text{d}t}=\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{x}(t)
$$

Admits the solution:
$$
\mathbf{x}(t)=\mathbf{x}(0)\text{exp}\left({\int^t_0\mathbf{A}(\tau)\,\text{d}\tau}\right)
$$

If the following property holds:

$$
\mathbf{A}(t)\mathbf{A}(\tau)=\mathbf{A}(\tau)\mathbf{A}(t)
$$

The property is also know as the matrix being *semi-proper*.

Is there an analytical solution for the cases when $\mathbf{A}(t)$ is not semi-proper?

If there is no analytical solution, how should one go about constructing an approximate solution? What methods are commonly used?

Comment: @Amzoti: Thank you! I've seen something like this before, but what I was curious about is whether or not there are some papers which deal with trying to construct a solution based on less constraining conditions than the matrix having to be semi-proper.